# Not able to parse date information in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have moved some data from MongoDB to BigQuery. Unfortunately the MongoDB source is not accessible now. I am able parse most of the information with help of [stackoverflow community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66766498), [Alessandro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4018047/alessandro) helped me out however I am having trouble with **parsing date information**. Following is sample data I have created

```
with cte as (
    select 12829 as user_id,
    '[{"_id":{"$oid":"5d650676af82eb0a30737e74"},"_type":"UserName","capture_date":{"$date":"2019-08-27T00:00:00.000+0000"},"source":"google","name1":"John","name3":"Doe","name4":"D/O Jane Doe","gender":"1","dob":{"$date":"1986-07-10T00:00:00.000+0000"}}]' as json_line
)
select
    user_id,
    json_value(json_line, '$[0].name1') as name1,
    json_value(json_line, '$[0].capture_date') as capture_date,
    PARSE_DATE('{"$date":"%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00.000+0000"}', json_value(json_line, '$[0].capture_date')) as capture_date1
from cte
```

I have already tried using parse_date, it wasn't useful. Could you please help me with **my fault** in provided approach or if there is **any better approach** to solve the same problem?

I am trying to parse cature_date information and I am getting null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [json_extract_scalar](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_scalar):

```
with cte as (
    select 12829 as user_id,
    '[{"_id":{"$oid":"5d650676af82eb0a30737e74"},"_type":"UserName","capture_date":{"$date":"2019-08-27T00:00:00.000+0000"},"source":"google","name1":"John","name3":"Doe","name4":"D/O Jane Doe","gender":"1","dob":{"$date":"1986-07-10T00:00:00.000+0000"}}]' as json_line
)
select
    user_id,
    json_extract(json_line, '$[0].name1') as name1,
    json_extract_scalar(json_line, "$[0].capture_date['$date']") as capture_date,
    PARSE_DATE("%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00.000+0000", json_extract_scalar(json_line, "$[0].capture_date['$date']")) as capture_date1,
from cte
```

or `json_value`:

```
with cte as (
    select 12829 as user_id,
    '[{"_id":{"$oid":"5d650676af82eb0a30737e74"},"_type":"UserName","capture_date":{"$date":"2019-08-27T00:00:00.000+0000"},"source":"google","name1":"John","name3":"Doe","name4":"D/O Jane Doe","gender":"1","dob":{"$date":"1986-07-10T00:00:00.000+0000"}}]' as json_line
)
select
    user_id,
    json_extract(json_line, '$[0].name1') as name1,
    json_value(json_line, '$[0].capture_date."$date"') as capture_date,
    PARSE_DATE("%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00.000+0000", json_value(json_line, '$[0].capture_date."$date"')) as capture_date1,
from cte
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome :) Thanks for quick help